# Docker copy src

Tags: docker

My project hierarchy is as such:

```
docker-flowcell-restore
    docker-flowcell-restore
        config
        src
        requirements.txt
        Dockerfile
```

I would like to add my src file to my docker image using Copy. So far my Docker image has the following:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python3 \
python3-pip

ENV INSTALL_PATH /docker-flowcell-restore
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ['python', 'docker-flowcell-restore/src/main.py']
```

How do I add the copy of the contents of the src folder? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the copy after your pip install command. This leverages the docker layer cache so you don't rerun the install of all the requirements after a change to different parts of your code:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV INSTALL_PATH /docker-flowcell-restore
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ src/

ENTRYPOINT ['python', 'src/main.py']
```

I've also added steps to cleanup the apt cache after performing the install, and adjusted the entrypoint since the `WORKDIR` was defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python3 \
python3-pip

ENV INSTALL_PATH /docker-flowcell-restore
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY ./src <the path inside the container where you want src>

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ['python', 'docker-flowcell-restore/src/main.py']
```

This is assuming that you are building your image from the directory where the Dockerfile is located.